# If number is 5609 output is "This number is prime", even though I know it's not a prime number

Tags: python

If number is 5609 output is "This number is prime",even though I know it's not a prime number. Why am I getting that output?
With several other casual numbers it works.

```
    number = int(input())
    if number <= 1:
        print("This number is not prime")

    for i in range(2, number):
        if number % i == 0:
            print("This number is not prime")
            break
        print("This number is prime")
        break
```

Comment: You have a ``break`` both inside *and* outside the ``if``: *every* path inside the ``for`` loop ends with a ``break``. This means it exits after the first ``i`` already. Why do you have the final ``break``?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check *all* the possible factors before declaring `number` to be prime; you do so as soon as the first value of `i` (2) does not divide it.

The quickest fix is to move the last `print` statement out of the body of the loop to an `else` block *following* the loop.

```
number = int(input())
if number <= 1:
    print("This number is not prime")

for i in range(2, number):
    if number % i == 0:
        print("This number is not prime")
        break
else:
    print("This number is prime")
```

The `else` block is only executed if the loop exits "naturally", by exhausting its iterators, rather than by a `break` statement.

Comment: I didn't know you could put else statement outside of for-loop like this.  But seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

That works only with non-primes which are even numbers. This should work better (last print ouside of for-loop)

```
    number = int(input())
    prime = True
    if number <= 1:
        print("This number is not prime")

    for i in range(2, number):
        if number % i == 0:
            prime = False
            print("This number is not prime")
            break
    # Print this when all numbers are looped.
    if prime:
        print("This number is prime")
```

Comment: Yes, you were right. Now that's fixed

Comment: Note that there is a typo - ``prime`` versus ``Prime``. Also, this pattern is natively expressed using ``for``-``else``.

Comment: Fixed that typo as well. And yes, learning every day something new.  I didn't know that for - else -structure before.